# Should the weights be rotated when using SciPy full convolution?

Tags: gradient-descent, convolution, backpropagation, scipy

I use SciPy's [single.convolve2d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html) in "full" mode to compute gradient w.r.t to convolution layer inputs. In my current implementation, I don't rotate filters as suggested by this [article](http://soumith.ch/ex/pages/2014/08/07/why-rotate-weights-convolution-gradient/) because I assume that the signal.convolve2d handles this internally.

```
full_conv = signal.convolve2d(global_grad, filters, boundary='fill', mode='full')
```

Since my gradient check did not pass I now think it must be something wrong and the filters should be rotated. Could someone help me clarify this point? thanks